# QSqlDatabase is opened but QSqlQuery does not execute and shows error database not opened

Tags: c++, qt, qtsql

I am working on a project. I am trying to run this query but it fails and gives the error. Here is the code:

```
 QSqlQuery* printQry = new QSqlQuery();     
    if(db.Connect()){
                qDebug() << "query is done" << printQry->exec("SELECT * FROM first_weight,second_weight where fID = sID and fID ="+sr+"");
                qDebug() << printQry->lastError().text();
                db.Disconnect();
            }
```

Here is the error:

```
Database open.
QSqlQuery::exec: database not open
query is done false
"Driver not loaded Driver not loaded"
Database close.
```

Database open shows that database is connected and opened but the query shows the error. Can someone please explain what I am doing wrong.
Thanks in advance

Comment: First open the database, then execute the query, not the other way round. Also there is no need to create a QSqlQuery in the heap.

Comment: Just a guess: maybe, you need to create `QSqlQuery` instance *after* you've opened the database.

Comment: The second one: maybe you need to specify your database in the constructor of `QSqlQuery`, if it's not a default database (https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqlquery.html#QSqlQuery-1).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem a couple of time ago.

You have first to open the database and assign an instance name  :

```
   connectToDatabase()
   {
   QString connectString ;

    connectString = QString("DRIVER=SQL Server;Server=%1;Database=%2;uid=%3;pwd=%4")
        .arg(m_params.hostName)
        .arg(m_params.dataBaseName)
        .arg(m_params.userName)
        .arg(m_params.password);



         m_db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC","connection-name" ); 
         m_db.setHostName("localhost");



         m_db.setDatabaseName(connectString);  

         if(m_db.open())
         {
            qDebug() << "Connected to :" << m_db.hostName() ;
  
         }
         else
         {
           qDebug() << "Fail :" << m_db.lastError().text() ;
         }
          }
```

Note that here my instance name is "connection-name". Then, to execute a query, you have to refer to this name :

```
  executeQueryFirstTable()
    {
          QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::database("connection-name");
        QSqlQuery query(db); 
       QString requestForFirstTable = "INSERT INTO...";

    if(query.exec(requestForFirstTable))  
    {
        qDebug() << "Done !";
    }
}
```

Works fine with MS SQL Server.

Your log is saying that you have a driver problem, make sure to read this :  https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sql-driver.html